# C++ socket: trasmitting special characters

Tags: c++, sockets, openssl, unsigned-char, aes-gcm

I'm using libcrypto library in order to use AES256-GCM. In this modality, the encryption process returns a "tag" which is the MAC of the encrypted data. (Other details here https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption).
I tested my class and it works in the sense that: it encrypts data, it decrypts them and it verifies the integrity by using the "tag".

If I do the same thing in a server-client architecture in which they communicate with sockets, the tag verification does not work.

Client

```
//NOTE: I reported only the relevant parts

unsigned char tag[BLOCK_SIZE];

aes_256_gcm_encrypt(key, iv, ptext, ctext, tag);

//some code to send the cypertext (ctext)

//Send TAG
if( write(sock , tag , sizeof(tag)) < 0) {
    puts("Send tag failed");
    return 1;
}
for(int i=0; i< sizeof(tag) ; i++){
    cout << "tag[" << i << "] "<<tag[i] << endl;
}
```

It prints 12 very "strange" characters. I think this is a problem when I write them on the socket.

Server

```
//NOTE: I reported only the relevant parts

unsigned char tag[BLOCK_SIZE];

int read_size2 = read(sock , tag , 12);
printf("read size2 =%i\n\n", read_size2);

for(int i=0; i< sizeof(tag) ; i++){
   cout << "tag[" << i << "] "<<tag[i] << endl;
}

//some code to receive the cypertext (ctext)

int ret = aes_256_gcm_decrypt(key, iv, ctext, rtext,tag);

 if(ret > 0){
    puts("Decryption says that authentication is OK\n");
 }else{
    puts("Decryption says that authentication is NOT OK\n");
 }

 cout << "client decrypted message: " << rtext.data() << endl << endl;
```

Server prints the SAME 12 characters of the Client but "ret" (which says if the authentication over ciphertext performed by using the tag is ok) is always <= 0. I don't understand why by passing "tag" over sockets, compromises the integrity verification.

Comment: Does the `aes_256_gcm_decrypt()` call work when you put it in the client? It's highly unlikely that the data is being damaged when transmitted over the socket.  It's more likely that either the encrypt or decrypt functions are failing for other reasons.

Comment: I if execute encryption and decryption on client, it works and I don't have this problem.

Comment: Have you verified that the key and IV are identical? Consider writing out the contents of the buffer as numbers (use `static_cast<int>(tag[i])` in your `cout` lines) to prove to yourself that the data has not been damaged.

Comment: Yes, IV and key are identical in fact the decrypted text on the server side is correct. If I print by using static_cast<int>(tag[i]), I obtain same values on server and client.

Comment: Maybe there is a \0 at the end of the cyphertext or to the fact that ctex,ptext are defined in this way:

typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, zallocator<char> > secure_string;

Comment: I solved by changing the tag size from BLOCK_SIZE to 16.